# Circular component dependency detected:

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I am using *Autofac* to DI and getting Circular component dependency detected  error

My implementation looks like

```
public interface IProduct { }

public class Product : IProduct { }

public interface ISupplier { }

public class Supplier : ISupplier { }

public interface IProductSupplier { }

public class ProductSupplier : IProductSupplier
{
    private ProductSupplier(ISupplier supplier, IProduct product) { }
}

public interface IGoodsReceive { }

public class GoodsReceive : IGoodsReceive
{
    private GoodsReceive(IProductSupplier productSupplier) { }
}
```

while resolving ProductSupplier , it gives Circular component dependency detected: GoodsReceive -> productSupplier -> productSupplier

Comment: The error indicates that productSupplier need a productSupplier. In your sample you have private constructor, it seems that this sample doesn't reflect the actual code. Could you update your code with all your constructors ?

Comment: As @CyrilDurand wrote, there are no circular dependencies in the code you showed as, especially not the one you mentioned in you question

Comment: @Cyril, I debugged more into found out that the IProductSupplier was deriving ISupplier, IProduct. Once i removed those, it is worked fine.